# encode €-sign in POST for HTML

Tags: android, post, http-post, url-encoding

I send a query to a php file in order to receive a xml:

```
www.mydomain.com/order.php?item=€15,- shoes
```

For HTML I need the €-sign as: & e u r o ;

I tried:

```
try {
            query=URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

And the POST-url=`www.mydomain.com/order.php?query`

Problem with that is that the = sign also becomes encoded, and I get the error for the & e u r o ; (the ;-sign):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index
```

How do I encode this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to encode your whole query string.

Encode each parameter value before constructing the query string.

eg:

```
query = "item=" + URLEncoder.encode("€15")
```

Also, if you want `&euro` that's not URL encoded but HTML escaped. Use URL encoding instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace € sign with a different character and convert it back again. The € symbol is not ASCII.

Comment: Thought it is extended ASCII? (%80)

Answer (score 0):

I use similar to your code :

```
String query="www.mydomain.com/order.php?item=€15,- shoes";


        try {
            query=URLEncoder.encode(query,"UTF-8");
            System.out.println(query);

            String decoQuery=URLDecoder.decode(query);
            System.out.println(decoQuery);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

output:

```
www.mydomain.com%2Forder.php%3Fitem%3D%E2%82%AC15%2C-+shoes
www.mydomain.com/order.php?item=€15,- shoes
```

are you sure you have correct encoding file for as UTF-8 for your project under your IDE . 
i.e. eclipse : right mouse on project ==> resource ==> text file encoding ==> put it UTF-8